# Object under mouse beyond near clipping plane

Tags: math, opengl, matrix, 3d

I have a perspective projection. I want to have an object follow the mouse. It works fine when I set the object to be almost on a near clipping plane. But as the object goes beyond the near clipping plane, its movement is more and more distorted in a comparison to the mouse position. I know I need to change X and Y coordinates to reflect modified Z, but I don't know exact equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport limits map to the near plane, so close to the near plane the scaling factor is ~1. So all you have to do is to scale by the distance of the object in view coordinates in relation to the distance of the near clipping plane:

```
scale = Z_object / Z_near
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by view coordinates here. Znear in view coordinates is 0, isn't it?

Comment: No, the near plane distance is in view space. I.e. Znear is the closest distance that's not getting clipped.